# jQuery: Filter classes and search for element with same class

Tags: jquery, filter, addclass, removeclass

```js
$("#add-btn-text").click(function(){
     var $that   = $(this),
        classes = $that.attr('class'),
        theDynamicClass = classes.replace('btn', '').replace('btn-primary', '').trim(),
  
        $boxWithSameClass = $(".li."+theDynamicClass);

     $boxWithSameClass.toggleClass("hide-me added");
     
});
```

```css
.hide-me {color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);}
.added {color:rgba(0,0,0,1);}
.top-added {color: rgba(0,170,200,1);}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="col-md-4 label-wrap">
 <h1 class="top-service">header</h1>
  <ul class="li-wrap">
   <li class="hide-me add-btn point dynamicClass1" id="1a">lorem 1</li>
   <li class="hide-me add-btn point dynamicClass2">lorem 2</li>
   <li class="hide-me add-btn point dynamicClass3">lorem 3</li>
   </ul>
</div>


<div class="row row-centered">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-centered service-detail">
  <h2>lorem 1</h2>
  <h3>subhead</h3>
   <p>some text</p>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-2 col-centered service-detail service-pos">
  <ul class="service-btn-2">
   <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-btn-text" data-dynamicclass="dynamicClass1">add</button></li>
   <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">other button</button></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have several div's with buttons. On click each button should add a class to a li with the same class like the button.

I searched and found a solution, which I think would fit, but I can't get it to work.

The Jquery-Code:

```
$("#add-btn-text").click(function(){
    var $that   = $(this),
    classes = $that.attr('class'),
    theDynamicClass = classes.replace('btn', '').replace('btn-primary', '').trim(),

    $boxWithSameClass = $(".li."+theDynamicClass);

    $boxWithSameClass.toggleClass("hide-me added");     
});
```

As I understand it, if u click on the button, the dynamic class filters out the other classes and leaves only the "dynamic" one, which is different on each button. Next the boxWithSameClass identifies the li in an other div, which has the same "dynamic" class and adds/removes the wanted/not-wanted class to/from the li.

Am I right? I don't understand, why it is not working.

HTML-Code BUTTON:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-centered service-detail service-pos">
   <ul class="service-btn-2">
     <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary exp" id="add-btn-text">Hinzufügen</button></li>
     <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Details</button></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

HTML-Code LIST:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
   <ul>
     <li class="exp">Exposés</li>
     <li>Textdesign</li>
     <li>Anzeigenkampagnen</li>
     <li>Geschäfts- und Presseberichte</li>
     <li>Bautafelgestaltung</li>
     <li>Außenwerbung</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hide-me {color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);}
.added {color:rgba(0,0,0,1);}
.top-added {color: rgba(0,170,200,1);}
```

In addition, what I am trying to do is:

The user can click different li's, which will be highlighted. ALL highlighted li shall be transfered by a form. That means, a customer wants an exposé, so he clicks on exposé, which is now visible. 
Now, the customer fills out the bystanding form and sends it. EVERY highlighted li should be send with it.

Is this possible? I am not sure what I should search for to find a thread about this topic. 
This is only an additional question. Would be glad if someone could give me a hint. ;)

Comment: Can you please provide fiddle for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This [JS FIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xxb7fd8q/7/)

```
$('.service-btn-2').on('click','button', function(){
    var btn_class =  $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
$('.whatever').find('.'+btn_class[0]).toggleClass("hide-me");
```

});

On click on button you wanted to toggle a class to li with same class. If it is not correct, Please correct me :)

Comment: as simple as that. Thank you.
I only have to make sure, that the different classes on the different li are in the first spot. Am I right?

Comment: Each ul with the highlighted li has an header h1.

The li now toggles correctly, and in addition I want the h1 closest to this li inside the same div to add a class.
My code

`$('.service-btn-2').on('click','button', function(){`
   `var btn_class =  $(this).attr('class').split(" ");`
      `$('.label-wrap ul').find('.'+btn_class[0]).toggleClass("hide-me added"); `
   `var $wrap = $('li').closest('.label-wrap');`
      `$wrap.find('h1').toggleClass('top-added', $wrap.find('.added').length > 0);`
  });`


But now EVERY header of the 3 divs get this added Class..Why??

Comment: Yes sir, You are right :) .. if you think it is right answer Please accept the answer . For this you can Simply add the line as in  https://jsfiddle.net/xxb7fd8q/9/ :

  $('.whatever').find('.'+btn_class[0]).closest('div').find('h1').addClass('active');

Answer (score 0):

your button HTML is this

`<li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-btn-text" data-dynamicclass="dynamicClass1">add</button></li>`

you have the dynamic class value in `dynamicclass="dynamicClass1"` and not in the `class` attribute. But in your jquery you are trying to get the dynamic value from class attribute that's the mistake.

Your mistake.

```
classes = $that.attr('class'),
theDynamicClass = classes.replace('btn', '').replace('btn-primary', '').trim(),
```

Change your logic to **read the dynamic class from the `data` attribute** like below

```
theDynamicClass = $that.data('dynamicclass');
```

Also the `toggleClass` arguments are not right, you must pass a single argument/class

So your final function code would be like below.

```
$("#add-btn-text").click(function(){
        var $that   = $(this);   // make sure you end each line with a ;
        theDynamicClass = $that.data('dynamicclass');

        $boxWithSameClass = $("li."+theDynamicClass);

        $boxWithSameClass.toggleClass("hide-me").toggleClass("added");
});
```

Hope this helps

**EDIT 1:** There was one more mistake in the selectors `$(".li."+theDynamicClass)` it should be `$("li."+theDynamicClass)` Note there is no `.` before the `li`. Working Demo below Also I have changed the jquery to latst version `2.1.1` . If you want to for some reason use the older version itself then you must change the code to

`theDynamicClass = $that.attr('data-dynamicclass');` as the `data` property came only after 1.4.3 version.

```js
$("#add-btn-text").click(function(){
    debugger;
    var $that   = $(this);   // make sure you end each line with a ;
    theDynamicClass = $that.data('dynamicclass');

    $boxWithSameClass = $("li."+theDynamicClass);

    $boxWithSameClass.toggleClass("hide-me").toggleClass("added");
});
```

```css
.hide-me {color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);}
.added {color:rgba(0,0,0,1);}
.top-added {color: rgba(0,170,200,1);}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="col-md-4 label-wrap">
 <h1 class="top-service">header</h1>
  <ul class="li-wrap">
   <li class="hide-me add-btn point dynamicClass1" id="1a">lorem 1</li>
   <li class="hide-me add-btn point dynamicClass2">lorem 2</li>
   <li class="hide-me add-btn point dynamicClass3">lorem 3</li>
   </ul>
</div>


<div class="row row-centered">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-centered service-detail">
  <h2>lorem 1</h2>
  <h3>subhead</h3>
   <p>some text</p>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-2 col-centered service-detail service-pos">
  <ul class="service-btn-2">
   <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-btn-text" data-dynamicclass="dynamicClass1">add</button></li>
   <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">other button</button></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's my fault, indeed. But it doesn't work yet.

It says: $boxWithSameClass not defined. Same with theDynamicClass and the last line. Don't know why...*?*

Comment: I bought a template, which is based on an older version of jquery.

Hm, if I wanted to update, must I only change the version? Will the older script still function?

Comment: Yes most of it must work... there are few things which have deprecated over the version changes.. It would be  better if you can contact the template guys and ask for a updated version.. if they are still supporting the template development may be they will have a new version .. better have a check ..